# Ошибки при запуске программы отправки email с помощью TLS

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <groupId>email_</groupId>
        <artifactId>email_</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

При запуске программы выходят ошибки:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.example.JavaGmailSendExample.main(JavaGmailSendExample.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.example.JavaGmailSendExample.main(JavaGmailSendExample.java:45)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1418)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 31 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
This!

Ты как бы понимаешь, что tls и ssl работают по сертификатами, так?

А что же ты путь не указал до него тогда?

Вот, на, кури https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed+sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException